# In Django, When I updated the published date How I get the link from get_absolute_url is updated?

Tags: python, django

I built a Django blog application and I updated the published date
I found a result from get_absolute_url function is not updated
it always get the original link

models.py

```
#-- models.py --
#Create custom manager
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from slugify import slugify

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, slugify(self.slug)])

class Post(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft','Draft'),('published','Published'),)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date = 'publish',allow_unicode=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, slugify(self.slug)])
```

Views.py

```
#--views.py--
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404,get_list_or_404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Post



def post_list(request):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'page':page,'posts':posts})

# Create second views
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,slug=post,status='published',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
    return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',{'post':post})

class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'
```

template 
list.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %} My Blog {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1> My Blog </h1>
  {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
    <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
      {{ post.title }}
    </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="date">
      Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
     </p>
     {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% include "pagination.html" with page=page_obj %}
{% endblock %}
```

the code has generated result like this
http://localhost:8000/blog/2019/6/7/mydjango-first-time/

I expect the result should be updated to be 
http://localhost:8000/blog/2019/6/8/mydjango-first-time/

Pic#1
[the publihed date is updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYpW6.png)
Pic#2
[get_absolute_url is not updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwrQZ.png) 
Pic#3
[Page not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zp15.png)
Pic#4
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzHjE.png)

my first idea 
I deleted the item (at Django admin section) and insert a new record with all same data(except date) but It's still same error (Page not found).
Even I try to delete cache in **pycache** folder it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your publish field does not get updated from the code I can see. How do you edit your post? Via a form in the frontend? If so, your view code should update the publish field after save.

Your publish function should be:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ....

    def publish(self):
        self.publish = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    # or override the save
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.status == 'published':
            self.publish = timezone.now()
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or do it via the signal approach which I am not going to demonstrate here, you get the idea. Main thing is to update the `publish` field.

Comment: Hi, James
It works.
I'm a new learner for Django framework from this answer I learn how to override the save method.
Thank you very much.

Kapolo

Comment: Glad it helped.